How to make excel column as mandatory field on the bases of another column values
I have excel in which I need to ask from employee to share his/her work from office plan. I need comment if any employee is not coming office 3 days in a week. Means if any user select work from home for 3 days in a week than he/she need to update comment column. 

Something like: =IF(COUNTIF(D5:H5,"WFH")>=3,"Comment","")?

" he/she need to update comment column " >> just put the instruction at the header then.. They'll be able to see it and respond to it professionally. imho
